# Is it possible to change the language of a 2009 Mazda Axela stereo and navigation system from Japanese to English?

Tags: mazda, audio, navigation, mazda-3

I have a 2009 Mazda Axela which comes with a navigation and stereo system that is in Japanese. Is it possible to change the language to English?

[image]

Comment: Did anyone find a way to change the language of this model? I found no firmware and no setting to change it!

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try if your メニュー option (Menu) has a 設定 (Settings) option and inside there, a 言語 (Language) option. If it does, then most likely you can switch between the default 日本語 (Japanese) and 英語 (English).

If you don't find it there but you own the car, it could be a matter of researching what Pioneer unit you have and get an update, but chances are you have a domestic unit that hasn't been localized into English. If you own the car it might be worthwile bringing it to a Mazda shop, they will help you out.

Hope it helped!